# Mypy failing when you type hint with a more general type

Tags: python, mypy

I was writing some code and I found the following behaviour in mypy:

```py
from typing import Dict, TypedDict


class SomeDictionary(TypedDict):
    key: str


def function() -> Dict:
    some_dictionary: SomeDictionary = {"key": "value"}
    return some_dictionary
```

As you can see, in this example we have a `TypedDict`. We return one instance of that type inside a function, but the the function signature is set to a more general type: a simple dict. I was expecting this to work pretty nicely, because at the end of the day, the typed dict `SomeDictionary` is a dictionary. So I'm returning the correct type. Nonetheless, I'm getting the following error:

```
main.py:10: error: Incompatible return value type (got "SomeDictionary", expected "Dict[Any, Any]")  [return-value]
```

This can be reproduced in [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11). Maybe I'm not understanding how mypy works correctly, but for me right now this behaviour is pretty weird. Any reason to it? Or any way to fix it? Rather than changing the signature of `function`.

Comment: Using `Mapping` instead of `Dict` works, but I cannot explain exactly why.

Comment: This is one of those liskov substitution covariant/invariant/contravariant thingies.  If you return a `Dict`, it allows the caller to mutate your `some_dictionary` in ways that violate its `TypedDict` definition.  If you return a `Mapping` it's fine because a `Mapping` is typed as immutable, so if the caller tries to add a key the typechecker will stop it there.  In general you should always return a `Mapping` if the caller isn't supposed to modify the dict.